# Question about AWS Cognito replication between regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, replication

I have a question about AWS Cognitos replication between regions (Example: Region A - primary site / Region B - standby site).

At this time it is known that user pools (Cognitos) can be replicated in another region. However the original passwords of users (we can say, in Region A) are not migrated to Region B.
If we want to failover to Region B (for example, because the Region A is not available for some reason), the users in Region B will need to create new passwords, since Congnito does not replicate passwords,

The question is:

Are there any known workarounds to address the situation described ?
or
The only valid alternative in that scenario is for the user community to create new passwords in Region B (after a Failover) ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there isn't any. Best choice right now seems to be Okta or Auth0 or any self-managed solution.